# Not able to open react native project

Tags: react-native

ReactNative:Failed to parse React Native CLI configuration: groovy.json.JsonException: Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object

The current character read is 'E' with an int value of 69
Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object
line number 1
index number 0
Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/home/sanju/AwesomeProject/android/app/build/generated/not_namespaced_r_class_sources/debug/processDebugResources/r/com'    at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:904:18)    at GlobSync._readdir (/home/sanju/AwesomeProject/node_modules/glob/sync.js:288:41)    at GlobSync._readdirInGlobStar (/home/sanju/AwesomeProject/node_modules/glob/sync.js:267:20)    at GlobSync._readdir (/home/sanju/AwesomeProject/node_modules/glob/sync.js:276:17)    at GlobSync._processReaddir (/home/sanju/AwesomeProject/node_modules/glob/sync.js:137:22)    at GlobSync._process (/home/sanju/AwesomeProject/node_modules/glob/sync.js:132:10)    at GlobSync._processGlobStar (/home/sanju/AwesomeProject/node_modules/glob/sync.js:380:10)    at GlobSync._process (/home/sanju/AwesomeProject/node_modules/glob/sync.js:130:10)    at GlobSync._processGlobStar (/home/sanju/AwesomeProject/node_modules/glob/sync.js:383:10)    at GlobSync._process (/home/sanju/AwesomeProject/node_modules/glob/sync.js:130:10)
^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script '/home/sanju/AwesomeProject/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle' line: 200
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

  > Failed to parse React Native CLI configuration. Expected running 'npx --quiet --no-install react-native config' command from '/home/sanju/AwesomeProject' directory to output valid JSON, but it didn't. This may be caused by npx resolving to a legacy global react-native binary. Please make sure to uninstall any global 'react-native' binaries: 'npm uninstall -g react-native react-native-cli' and try again
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
:ReactNative:Failed to parse React Native CLI configuration: groovy.json.JsonException: Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object

The current character read is 'E' with an int value of 69
Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object
line number 1
index number 0
Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/home/sanju/AwesomeProject/android/app/build/generated/not_namespaced_r_class_sources/debug/processDebugResources/r/com'    at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:904:18)    at GlobSync._readdir (/home/sanju/AwesomeProject/node_modules/glob/sync.js:288:41)    at GlobSync._readdirInGlobStar (/home/sanju/AwesomeProject/node_modules/glob/sync.js:267:20)    at GlobSync._readdir (/home/sanju/AwesomeProject/node_modules/glob/sync.js:276:17)    at GlobSync._processReaddir (/home/sanju/AwesomeProject/node_modules/glob/sync.js:137:22)    at GlobSync._process (/home/sanju/AwesomeProject/node_modules/glob/sync.js:132:10)    at GlobSync._processGlobStar (/home/sanju/AwesomeProject/node_modules/glob/sync.js:380:10)    at GlobSync._process (/home/sanju/AwesomeProject/node_modules/glob/sync.js:130:10)    at GlobSync._processGlobStar (/home/sanju/AwesomeProject/node_modules/glob/sync.js:383:10)    at GlobSync._process (/home/sanju/AwesomeProject/node_modules/glob/sync.js:130:10)
^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script '/home/sanju/AwesomeProject/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle' line: 200
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

  > Failed to parse React Native CLI configuration. Expected running 'npx --quiet --no-install react-native config' command from '/home/sanju/AwesomeProject' directory to output valid JSON, but it didn't. This may be caused by npx resolving to a legacy global react-native binary. Please make sure to uninstall any global 'react-native' binaries: 'npm uninstall -g react-native react-native-cli' and try again
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s

```
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:601:13)
at execFileSync (child_process.js:621:13)
at runOnAllDevices (/home/sanju/AwesomeProject/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:94:39)
at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

Comment: Did you try remove node_modules and re-installing it ?

Comment: yes it did not help

Comment: try "cd android" in your project directory and then "./gradlew clean" and then try again

Comment: ~/Android$ ./gradlew clean
bash: ./gradlew: No such file or directory

Comment: sure you are in your android folder and run './gradlew clean' ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a temporary issue with the CLI. We're tackling it already [react-native-community/cli#863](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/863)